# Error when converting MySQL database scheme to SQLite using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I am trying to save Commander decks in a database using Python/SQLAlchemy.
I designed the database in MySQL using sqldbm and used SQLAlchemy docs to convert it as properly as I could.

The issue is that I continously get an `KeyError` when executing the code to commit decks:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myscript.py", line 359, in scrap_mtgtop8
    new_deck.commanders.append(card)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1130, in append
    item = __set(self, item, _sa_initiator, NO_KEY)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 1095, in __set
    item = executor.fire_append_event(item, _sa_initiator, key=key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/collections.py", line 687, in fire_append_event
    return self.attr.fire_append_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1756, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self._append_token, key=key)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 2207, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'deck'
```

I checked every relationship definition to be sure that they pointed in the right direction.
Here is part of the database definition:

```py
class Cartes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cartes"

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    mana_value = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    color_identity = Column(String, nullable=False)
    text = Column(String, nullable=False)
    first_print = Column(String, ForeignKey("sets.code"), nullable=False)
    legalities = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

    decks = relationship("DecksCartes", back_populates="carte")
    as_commander = relationship("DecksCommanders", back_populates="carte")


class Decks(Base):
    __tablename__ = "decks"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tournoi_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tournois.id"), nullable=False)
    rank = Column(String, nullable=False)
    player = Column(String, nullable=False)

    tournoi = relationship("Tournois", back_populates="decks")
    cartes = relationship("DecksCartes", back_populates="deck")
    commanders = relationship("DecksCommanders", back_populates="deck")


class DecksCartes(Base):
    __tablename__ = "decks_cartes"

    carte_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("cartes.id"), primary_key=True)
    deck_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("decks.id"), primary_key=True)

    carte = relationship("Cartes", back_populates="decks")
    deck = relationship("Decks", back_populates="cartes")


class DecksCommanders(Base):
    __tablename__ = "decks_commanders"

    deck_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("decks.id"), primary_key=True)
    carte_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("cartes.id"), primary_key=True)

    deck = relationship("Decks", back_populates="commanders")
    carte = relationship("Cartes", back_populates="as_commander")
```

The error is raised on the line `new_deck.commanders.append(card)`:

```py
deck_data = {
    "id": deck["id"],
    "tournoi_id": tournament.tournoi_id,
    "rank": deck["rank"],
    "player": deck["player"],
}
new_deck = Decks(**deck_data)

for card_name in deck["commander"]:
    card = session.query(Cartes).filter_by(name=card_name).first()
    new_deck.commanders.append(card)

for line in deck["decklist"]:
    qty, card_name = line.split(" ", maxsplit=1)
    card = session.query(Cartes).filter_by(name=card_name).first()

    if card:
        for _ in range(int(qty)):
            new_deck.cartes.append(card)

session.add(new_deck)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should review how to implement [bi-directional many to many relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#setting-bi-directional-many-to-many).